# ImportError: cannot import name 'trace' from 'tensorflow.python.profiler'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to run an object detection training on Tensorflow

Everything is working fine until I start training the network, here.

```
python C:\RealTimeObjectDetection-main\Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=C:\RealTimeObjectDetection-main\Tensorflow\workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path=C:\RealTimeObjectDetection-main\Tensorflow\workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet/pipeline.config --num_train_steps=200000
```

It produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\RealTimeObjectDetection-main\Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 32, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib_v2
  File "C:\Users\m8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 29, in <module>
    from object_detection import eval_util
  File "C:\Users\m8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\object_detection\eval_util.py", line 35, in <module>
    slim = tf.contrib.slim
  File "C:\Users\m8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 63, in __getattr__
    return getattr(module, item)
  File "C:\Users\m8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\m8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\m8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\m8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\contrib\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import compiler
  File "C:\Users\m8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\contrib\compiler\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.compiler import jit
  File "C:\Users\m8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\contrib\compiler\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.compiler import xla
  File "C:\Users\m8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\contrib\compiler\xla.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.estimator import model_fn as model_fn_lib
  File "C:\Users\m8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\estimator\model_fn.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import model_fn
  File "C:\Users\m8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1 import estimator
  File "C:\Users\m8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1.estimator import experimental
  File "C:\Users\m8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\experimental\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn import dnn_logit_fn_builder
  File "C:\Users\m8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\dnn.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import estimator
  File "C:\Users\m8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.profiler import trace
ImportError: cannot import name 'trace' from 'tensorflow.python.profiler' (C:\Users\m8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\profiler\__init__.py)
```

Software I am using: *Windows 10 - amd64*, *Python 3.7.0*, *TensorFlow 1.15.5*

Comment: Updating TensorFlow to version 2.3 or latest will fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

You can import this using latest Tensorflow version 2.6.

```
from tensorflow.python.profiler import trace
```

Comment: I have tensorflow version 2.6.0 installed 
```pip list | grep tensorflow
tensorflow                      2.6.0
tensorflow-estimator            2.6.0
tensorflow-object-detection-api 0.1.1
tensorflow-tensorboard          1.5.1```

I'm still getting this error

Comment: Hi.. was there a resolution?